# catch max_input_time php error

Tags: php

I need to prove to my sys admin that **max_input_time** in php.ini is what's stopping me from uploading large files to the server, but he wont increase it until I show him a proper error.

I looked at the manual but couldn't find anything about it.

Does anyone know of a method for proving this?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you so sure this is the problem?

Comment: Unless you are actually processing the files, running time should not be a problem.

Comment: Better take a look at `max_post_size` and `upload_max_filesize` settings.

Comment: because max upload size was already taking care of. and if I upload a file that does not take a lot of time it passes. but if it's a file that would take > max_input_time the uploading just stops at some point (excuse my poor english :p )

Comment: the limit is currenty 30 Mb and I'm uploading a 26Mb file. you should know that here in morocco, our upload rate is somewhere near 30kb/s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php.ini we see their possible values:

```
; max_input_time
;   Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
;   Development Value: 60 (60 seconds)
;   Production Value: 60 (60 seconds)
```

So check if is set to -1 (Unlimited time) uploading and running a script with:

```
<?php
// show current local and master values for PHP directives.
phpinfo(4);
?>
```

If you still believe that this value is the source of your pain, try to increase it by your own:

> `max_input_time` is changeable `PHP_INI_PERDIR` that means "Entry can
>   be set in php.ini, .htaccess or httpd.conf"

So you can try in .htaccess:

```
php_value max_input_time 120
```

---

OBS: In any case you can check the following post about all PHP directives relative to uploading files: http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php